# Does my Base Internationalization storyboard have to correspond to a fallback language for all unlocalized languages and strings?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, uistoryboard

I've looked through some internationalization documentation and videos on apple developer, but I never found an explicit answer to that question. In Apple's tutorials I see the `Base.lproj` folder alongside `en.lproj` and `zh.lproj` -- the example translation (localization) is from English to Chinese. But they tell me that there's a file `en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings`, and that is confusing. I can't see the point in creating an English localization for the storyboard (that is already in English).

1. So my questions are if the user will ever see the strings in the `Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard`?
2. Do the strings in that file have to be the default strings that are shown to the user if the system cannot find the user's preferred language folder in my bundle?
3. Can I explicitly say "never use `Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard`, always fall back on `en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings`"?

In other words:
Let's say I want my app to display in English whenever the user's language isn't available, but that my `Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard` is in Swedish. Do I then *have* to localize the Base Storyboard to `sv.lproj/myStoryboard.strings` and translate all strings in the Base storyboard to English to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial that suggests including "en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings"?

Comment: I believe this is the one that confused me: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

Comment: I might have misunderstood something in there, it was 2 months ago. Maybe it was just the Base.lproj and en.lproj folders that seemed redundant.

Comment: It's also the case that the default instance of the strings file for another language is going to start out with english text for the value. You're meant to replace those, but it might have been confusing that they started in english.

Comment: Yeah that was probably it. I don't understand why there has to be both a Base- and an en-folder though...

Comment: The en folder is typically going to be filed with localizable content that isn't from the storyboard. For example, user presented strings that are defined in code.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, XCode 5 didn't create a `en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings`, there's only the original storyboard in the `Base.lproj` folder. Maybe it's an old XCode issue?

Try to remove that file and see if your app gets along with Base.lproj for default, English strings.

Your Info.plist file should have an entry `Localization native development region`, which points to the lproj folder to be used in case the required string doesn't exist in the preferred language.

I'm not sure about this, but I think you have to use `en` and UI with a `Base.lproj` would automatically fallback to `Base.lproj`.

Does that help you in any way?

Comment: I had so much trouble with exploring localization in Xcode that I had chosen to just read up on the subject without trying anything in Xcode :) (first time I did my storyboard went to the trash and I got duplicate localizations that couldn't be removed etc.). 

The plist property sounds like just what I was looking for, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. So my questions are if the user will ever see the strings in the Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard?

It is the default to use those strings for the development region localization, which is typically English. If there was a matching strings file for english, it would supersede the strings in the storyboard. This is typically redundant, so it isn't normally used. If you really want all of your languages to be handled identically, you can do this.

> Do the strings in that file have to be the default strings that are shown to the user if the system cannot find the user's preferred language folder in my bundle?

These are unrelated concepts. The strings embedded in the storyboard are equivalent to having ones in en.lproj. After that, language fallback works the same as without Base.lproj.

> Can I explicitly say "never use Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard, always fall back on en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings"?

If you have en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings, and english is the development language, they will always superseded the strings embedded in Base.lproj/myStoryboard.storyboard for English. Including when English isn't the preferred language, but ends up being chosen as the fallback language.

Comment: Could you clarify "and english in the development" please?

Comment: I can't remember having seen "development language" as an option anywhere before, but then again I never looked for it. I'm guessing this is the same option as `localization native development region` that Kof mentions. Considering Kof's answer, "development language" seems just as unrelated to a fallback language as does Base internationalization. In my case my dev language is Swedish but the preferred fallback language would still be English. Confusing!

Comment: In my case development language english, but interestingly en.lproj/myStoryboard.strings doesn't supersede the strings in the storyboard. @Andreas, did you find solution?