# IOS: set a default language in xcode for my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, xcode5

I started my xcode project and I have these settings:

[image]

In xcode 5 it add this "base" language, but I don't understand how it works.
I want to set as my default language english and not italian; for example if an user set its device in spanish or in french language it must see app in english and not in italian;
can you help me?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114994/does-my-base-internationalization-storyboard-have-to-correspond-to-a-fallback-la

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

you should set "base" in in plist file section:

```
Localization native development region
```

and set Storyboard only for "base"; for other language only in Localizable String

when you localize a file you should set base (for language default) and the other language you want to use.

In localizations (picture in my question) should be with base and all language you want to use

Comment: where is the `plist` file?

Comment: If your info.plist file has the value $(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE) for the Localization native development region, you can update that value with the info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232581/826946