# how to localize system alerts

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

I have converted my app from english language to turkish+english language. I have localized the app, but the system alerts do not change. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584984/ios-set-a-default-language-in-xcode-for-my-app

Answer (score 1):

These texts are provided by the system. So the language depends on the systemlanguage set in the preferences.

Comment: thanks for answering.but this does not changes.I dont knwo what is wrong all the other changes took effect.

Comment: You need to set 'Localized resources can be mixed' to true in your info.plist