# strange code in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I started XCode and now one of my .m files looks like this:

ˇáÌ _libcorecrypto.dylib   *#/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylibS106ˇáÚ˜ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…¿¡¬√≈∆«O8£‡Ù„L=E¢…Lﬁ-Ωˇá˜–*libdnsinfo.dylib   _ /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylibV453.16ˇá˜Ô˜ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…… ÀÃŒœ–OëZÓ'<ÖÇŸëïX±ˇà†\libJP2.dylib *N/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylibS843ˇàœˇŸ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…—“”‘’◊ÿŸ⁄Oò•õ˚ö¿>´µ§&¬˘e¶]ˇàê*com.apple.CoreText  *A/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreTextV275.14ˇà#Ø˜U260.0ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…‹›ﬁﬂ·‚„OU˜X≠Ó8cíÈGr‹Íé1ˇà#∞*libCoreVMClient.dylib   *V/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylibT24.4ˇà#ˇˇŸ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…—ÂÊÁËÍÎÏÌO…L7+8!:F®¬   ±œ˜Ùˇà$*com.apple.datadetectorscore   _Z/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCoreU269.1ˇà*ﬂˇS4.0Ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…—ÔÒÚÙÌıˆOÇ‚KöwB=£ûôÌ&}ò¿^ ˇà.‡_com.apple.NetFS   _;/System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFSˇà/_ˇS5.0ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…¯˘˙˚˝˛ˇOO¸¢B6_á¶‘Ô∏ï¡!ˇà4@_libsystem_info.dylib   _$/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylibV406.17ˇà7ØˇŸ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…—ÍlOÒ‘=˚ñ6≠K9ÒÓ”æ"ˇà7∞_com.apple.ScalableUserInterface    _Ü/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ScalableUserInterface.framework/Versions/A/ScalableUserInterfaceˇà=/˜Ÿ¬√ƒ≈∆«»…—

Whats the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584984/ios-set-a-default-language-in-xcode-for-my-app

Comment: +1 for hardware problem

Comment: @hamstergene so the code is gone?

Comment: @user3298017 Yes, unless you are using version control system (which every developer absolutely *must* use), or if you have Time Machine active for that disk.